# How to place figcaption at the right side of figure?

Tags: html, css

Question is simple. About html, and css. How to place an html figcaption element at the right side (centered) to the img?

Answer (score 10):

`display: flex; align-tiems: center` on the parent.

```css
figure {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png">
  <figcaption>caption</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Or make them `inline-block` and use `vertical-align`

```css
img,figcaption {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png">
  <figcaption>caption</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 6):

If I have understood your question correctly you can achieve the effect you are after by using a combination of:

- `position: absolute;`
- `top: 0;`
- `right: 0;`
- `writing-mode: vertical-rl;`
- `text-align: center;`

**Working Example:**

```css
figure {
position: relative;
width: 334px;
height: 180px;
background-color: rgb(127, 127, 127);
}

figcaption {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
width: 24px;
height: 180px;
line-height: 24px;
font-size: 13px;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: center;
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
text-transform: uppercase;
writing-mode: vertical-rl;
}
```

```html
<figure>
<img src="http://placekitten.com/310/180" />
<figcaption>I am just a little cat</figcaption>
</figure>
```